# running time of pseudocode algorithm

Tags: algorithm, discrete-mathematics

This is an algorithm that I have been given to find the run time of.  I know how to do this fairly well except he has not explained what to do for while loops and he said he is not going to.  I also do not know what the syntax of begin and end is about.  He doesn't normally have that after a for loop, so since it is there now I am confused.

```
procedure f(n)
    s=0;
    for i=1 to 5n do
         begin
             j=4i;
             while j<i^3 do
                  begin
                       s=s+i-j
                       j=5j
                  end
         end
```

Comment: begin and end just mark a block of code.  It's like { } in C/C++/C#/Java

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the second loop we can see that the while loop starts from `4i` and ends after `k` iterations, where `k` is such that `4*i*5^k=i^3`, that is `k = log_5{i^2/4}`. So your run-time is:

[image]

In the second to last equation we used [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).